# regular expression to match nested brackets

Tags: regex, notepad++

I work in notepad++ and need to replace occurrences like

```
new int[(cw[0] - index) * 2];
```

It starts with "new int" followed by square brackets which may contain another pair of square brackets.

What is the regular expression for this?

Comment: Did you try anything? Please share.

Comment: Try this: new int\[.+\]

Comment: @Bifz You forgot to escape the brackets like so `new int\[.+\]`

Comment: What? I wrote them down escaped, don't know what happened :)

@WiktorStribiżew You told it could contain another pair of brackets...
If you want to stop at the first closing bracket, use new `int\[[^\]]+\]`

Comment: @Bifz: Use `\`` to enclose code in comments. No, those regexes won't help, because OP needs to match nested `[...]` brackets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In notepad++ the following should match occurrences:

```
new int(\[(?>[^\[\]]|(?1))*\])
```

This is leveraging recursion into a capture group to match the nested brackets as explained on ["matching balanced constructs" section](http://www.regular-expressions.info/subroutine.html)

Comment: Thank you for your guidance, I will keep this in mind moving forward.